# Cannot connect to SQL Server using Named Pipes through .NET application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, connection-string, named-pipes

First of all, I am trying to make this work because the "initial connection" of my Windows Forms application (run from Windows 10) to my SQL Server 2012 VM is taking too long (once connected all good). I read that by forcing/using Named Pipes instead of TCP/IP, there should be a considerable improvement on the above.

That being said, I have already read "a lot" and yes, I have found similar posts with the same regular error:

> The server was not found or was not accessible... Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

and I cannot figure out how to connect to SQL with NP protocol. I have tried to force it directly through the app connection string (Server=np:MyServer or np:\MyServer\pipe\sql\query or \MyServer\pipe\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER\sql\query or ;Network Library=dbnmpntw) without success.

Notes:

1. There is NO firewall enabled at the Windows 10 client nor at the Windows 2012 server.
2. There is only one instance (default MSSQLServer) at the SQL server.
3. Shared memory, Named Pipes, TCP/IP protocols are already enabled for the SQL instance in SQL Configuration Manager.
4. Named Pipes is using its defaults (no alias defined).
5. Of course I have already restarted the SQL Server service and even rebooted the server.

At this point for testing/replicating the problem, and if anybody there would like to assist this guy about to shoot himself, I am using Visual Studio - View - Server Explorer - Data Connections - Add Connection - Data provider .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server, test proper/successful connection to your SQL server (using TCP/IP) and then go to Advanced and adjust "Network Library" to Named Pipes (see below). Test Connection button again and if you figure out how to get a successful result, PLEASE let me know how! (the connection string in the new connection properties should do the trick)

**Visual Studio - Test new SQL Connection with Named Pipes**

[image: Visual Studio - Test new SQL Connection with Named Pipes]

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: How long does it take to connect?   It’s not likely to be a network issue.

Comment: Hi David, within 3-5 seconds. VM/server Windows/SQL2012 is in Hyper-V, same Windows 10 laptop (memory usage at 70% both client and server, processor Core i7 2.8Ghz 4 cores). Ping to server <1ms.

Comment: Does the database have [Auto Close Enabled](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-close-enabled/)? That can cause the first connection to be slow.

Comment: Negative, I am using the defaults and I can confirm that Auto Close is set to False, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't found a way to connect to the SQL server using Named Pipes protocol, I think I took the wrong path focusing on making that work. As I mentioned initially, my main goal was to improve the "initial connection" to the database, and I have already accomplished that. So, if this helps anybody there, it seemed to be a network related problem. Not sure if at the Hyper-V virtual switch level, but in any case:

1. Adjust your hosts file at the client workstation and add a direct entry to your server (i.e. 172.22.152.7  MyServer).
2. Be sure to set a fixed IP on your server.

With the above, the initial connection went from 3-5 seconds to almost immediately (0.5 s).

Additional notes:

1. Not a must but since I don't use/need IPv6, I disabled it at the virtual switch and at the server's NIC).
2. I assume putting the server's IP address directly in the connection string would have made it too. However, eventually, you may need to change IP so, I think it is better/easier to adjust this at the hosts file level.

Thanks for your attention,

M.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Hi Jiachen, I just did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Named pipes won’t be any faster.  In modern Windows it runs over TCP/IP for remote connections.

Comment: Just that it won't help.  So don't bother.  The time taken to connect is probably due to something else, like high resource utilization.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that the posts recommending forcing named pipes in the connection string were old (7-10 years ago), so, yes, your statement makes sense for me. That being said, are you saying that NP cannot even be used in my current scenario?

Comment: Will take that in consideration, thank you David for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

//I read that by forcing/using Named Pipes instead of TCP/IP, there should be a considerable improvement on the above.
//

That blanket statement is too assumption-filled.
You would have to setup both protocols (tcp or named-pipes) and perform actual metrics for "improvement" numbers/comparisons.

And I saying this from personal experience.  We (my company as a software vendor) had one client site...and they ran HORRIBLY under named-pipes.  We switched to tcp-ip, and everything ran very well.

I remember the on site trip very vividly.  My "booked hotel" reservation "ran out" (I had to stay extra days) and I had to stay one extra night in a cheap sleezy pay by the hour motel.  So trust me, I remember.  It was during this long trip at the client site where I initially learned about network-protocol/library settings.  And "dbmssocn" and I became friends. (see the list below in my answer)

Note, on windows-clients, if you do not specify the network-library....the windows machine itself will have a default (deep within the windows-registry)...so without being explicit in YOUR connection string, you are relying on the default of the windows-client-machine-registry-default.  Which could have its own differing-behavior implications.  << READ THIS AGAIN, THIS IS THE NOT-UNDERSTOOD part of the equation that some devs do not consider when they find the magic combination that works FOR THEIR SITUATION and then start authoring "blanket statements" like "tcp-ip stinks, always use named pipes".

```
Network protocol codes
NAME    NETWORK LIBRARY
dbnmpntw    Named Pipes
dbmslpcn    Shared Memory (local machine connections only, might fail when moving to production...)
dbmssocn    Winsock TCP/IP
dbmsspxn    SPX/IPX
dbmsvinn    Banyan Vines
dbmsrpcn    Multi-Protocol (Windows RPC)
dbmsadsn    Apple Talk
dbmsgnet    VIA
```

But more importantly, I was finally able to leave the client in good shape by changing TO tcp-ip FROM named pipes.
Thus why your question "hit a nerve" :)

With that said, my advice is:

Provide a "more exact string" under tcp/ip is where I would start.
The less "resolving" it has to do ... the better.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/define-sql-server-network-protocol/

> Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network
> Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=pubs;User
> ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

My experience has been, you give it an IP-ADDRESS (not a server "name") ...  AND a PORT ... AND the network-library to use... that is your best setup for "find it as soon as possible".

Note, you can also specify the "Network Library" that is named-piped flavored......but I would start with tcp/ip first IMHO.  If you get to that point, you can internet-search for

> "Network Library=dbnmpntw"

Here is a link to more connection-string options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, during my research I found and tried to force "Network Library=dbnmpntw" directly on the connection string and didn't work (I mentioned it BTW). Although I think you are giving good advice on being as specific as possible when defining a connection string, I can confirm that what makes the difference is specifying the server IP instead of the name. Somehow, at least in my current scenario, it is taking too much time to resolve the name. Still, I prefer to keep the server name at the conn string and adjust the hosts file as I mentioned below. Thanks again!